# How to overload unary & outside class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

You can overload the unary `&` operator inside a class as:

```
struct X
{
   void* operator &()
   {
      return this;
   }
};
```

so that it returns an address. How would you overload it outside of a class:

```
struct X
{
};

void* operator &(const X& x)
{
    //how?
}
```

Taking the address of the parameter would result in infinite recursion.

Comment: Why would you overload the operator to return the address of the object? It already does that.

Comment: @BoPersson for fun of course :)

Answer (score 5):

In C++11, there is `template< class T > T* std::addressof(T& arg)`.

[std::addressof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof)

You can also get the same function for C++03 from [Boost Utility](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/utility/utility.htm)

Comment: Just guessing here, but wouldn't addressof generate code that calls the same operator recursively?

Comment: No because internally `addressof` casts to char& before getting an address.

Comment: Right, `addressof` performs on your behalf "ugly casting tricks to avoid invoking the overloaded `operator&()`"

Comment: Since it's part of the C++11 standard now, it is, by definition, legal.